# SQL query for grouping and datetime difference

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm confused with query for grouping (or intersecting?) with specific params.

I have table with user's period of activity and table with periods.

I need query for making aggregation table with sum of seconds (or minutes), which user have been active during every period. And insert this results into another table.

Something like "insert into... select... group by".

User activity table:

```
UserId  DatetimeFrom       DatetimeTo        
1       2018-01-01 10:00   2018-01-01 11:30  
1       2018-01-01 13:45   2018-01-01 14:20  
2       2018-01-01 10:50   2018-01-01 11:30
```

Periods table:

```
PeriodId  DatetimeFrom       DatetimeTo        
1         2018-01-01 09:30   2018-01-01 10:15  
2         2018-01-01 10:15   2018-01-01 11:10  
3         2018-01-01 11:10   2018-01-01 12:00
4         2018-01-01 12:00   2018-01-01 13:30
5         2018-01-01 13:30   2018-01-01 15:00
```

Result table needed:

```
UserId  PeriodId  SumMinutes
1       1         15         //from 10:00 to 10:15 - period 1
1       2         55         //from 10:15 to 11:10 - period 2 
1       3         20         //etc
1       5         35
2       2         20
2       3         20
```

Thanks in advance!

UPD: thanks to everybody! All answers are usefull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a typo in your expected results (1, and periodId 5 should be 35, no?):

```
select a.UserID, p.PeriodId,
   datediff(minute,
   case when a.DateTimeFrom < p.DateTimeFrom 
        then p.DateTimeFrom else a.DateTimeFrom end,
   case when a.DateTimeTo > p.DateTimeTo 
        then p.DateTimeTo else a.DateTimeTo end) as minutes
from Activity a
inner join Periods p 
 on a.DateTimeTo > p.DateTimeFrom and 
    a.DateTimeFrom < p.DateTimeTo;
```

[SQLFiddle sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a438c/5)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for overlapping time periods -- and then adding them up.  Two periods overlap if the following is true:

- The first starts before the second ends.
- The first ends after the second starts.

Then, you can calculate the duration of the overlap by looking at the maximum of the start time and the minimum of the end time.

The SQL ends up looking like:

```
select p.DatetimeFrom, p.DatetimeTo,
       sum(datediff(minute,
                    (case when a.DatetimeFrom < p.DatetimeFrom then p.DatetimeFrom else a.DatetimeFrom end),
                    (case when a.DatetimeTo < p.DatetimeTo then a.DatetimeTo else a.DatetimeTo end)
                   )
           ) as overlap_minutes
from periods p left join
     activity a
     on a.DatetimeFrom < p.DatetimeTo and
        a.DatetimeTo > p.DatetimeFrom 
group by p.DatetimeFrom, p.DatetimeTo
order by p.DatetimeFrom, p.DatetimeTo
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need below query

```
insert into results 
select PeriodId,u.UserId, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, p.DatetimeFrom, p.DatetimeTo) as SumMinutes

 from Periods p left join users u 

 on u.DatetimeFrom < p.DatetimeTo and
        u.DatetimeTo > p.DatetimeFrom 
 order by u.UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to join a user activity table to a period table for each row in activity that has a datetime range that overlaps a datetime range in period. In addition, you want the result set to include a column with the calculated number of overlapping minutes.

The number of overlapping minutes can be expressed in various ways but let us express it as the difference between whichever is the highest of the user activity and period start times and the lowest of the user activity and period end times.

Then we can write:

```
DECLARE @UserActivity table (UserId int, DatetimeFrom datetime, DatetimeTo datetime)

DECLARE @Period table (PeriodId int, DatetimeFrom datetime, DatetimeTo datetime)

INSERT INTO @UserActivity (UserId, DatetimeFrom, DatetimeTo)
    VALUES (1,'2018-01-01 10:00','2018-01-01 11:30'),
        (1,'2018-01-01 13:45','2018-01-01 14:20'),
        (2,'2018-01-01 10:50','2018-01-01 11:30'),
        (3,'2018-01-01 11:10','2018-01-01 12:00')

INSERT INTO @Period (periodId, DatetimeFrom, DatetimeTo)
    VALUES (1,'2018-01-01 09:30','2018-01-01 10:15'),  
    (2,'2018-01-01 10:15','2018-01-01 11:10'),
    (3,'2018-01-01 11:10','2018-01-01 12:00'),
    (4,'2018-01-01 12:00','2018-01-01 13:30'),
    (5,'2018-01-01 13:30','2018-01-01 15:00')

SELECT _UserActivity.UserId, _Period.PeriodId, _UserActivity.DatetimeFrom AS UserActivityDatetimeFrom, _UserActivity.DatetimeTo AS UserActivityDatetimeTo, _Period.DatetimeFrom AS PeriodDatetimeFrom, _Period.DatetimeTo AS PeriodDatetimeTo,
    DATEDIFF(minute, (SELECT MAX(x) FROM (VALUES (_UserActivity.DatetimeFrom), (_Period.DatetimeFrom)) AS VALUE(x)), (SELECT MIN(x) FROM (VALUES (_UserActivity.DatetimeTo), (_Period.DatetimeTo)) AS VALUE(x))) AS ActivityWithinPeriod
FROM @UserActivity AS _UserActivity
INNER JOIN @Period AS _Period ON (_Period.DatetimeFrom <= _UserActivity.DatetimeFrom AND _Period.DatetimeTo > _UserActivity.DatetimeFrom)
    OR  (_Period.DatetimeFrom < _UserActivity.DatetimeTo AND _Period.DatetimeTo > _UserActivity.DatetimeTo)
ORDER BY UserId, PeriodId
```

The above assumes that the period datetimes are semi-open intervals (i.e. 9:30am to 10:15pm includes 9.30am but excludes 10:15pm).